# Creating a folder under Inbox using Mocrosoft.Graph 2.0.14

Tags: c#, office365api

I'm trying to create a folder under my Inbox in Office 365 using MS Graph 2.0, but I'm finding surprisingly little information on the topic anywhere on the internet. The authentication works fine, and I was able to read the existing test folder. My method for doing this is below:

```
private void SetupMailBoxes()
    {
        SmartLog.EnterMethod("SetupMailBoxes()");
        MailFolder inbox = null;
        try
        {
            bool dbErrorFolder = false;
            bool exchangeErrorFolder = false;
            inbox = _journalMailbox.MailFolders.Inbox.Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (inbox.ChildFolderCount > 0)
            {
                inbox.ChildFolders = _journalMailbox.MailFolders.Inbox.ChildFolders.Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            if (inbox.ChildFolders != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.ChildFolders.Count && (!dbErrorFolder  || !exchangeErrorFolder); i++)
                {
                    if (inbox.ChildFolders[i].DisplayName.ToLower() == "db-error-items")
                    {
                        dbErrorFolder = true;
                    }
                    else if (inbox.ChildFolders[i].DisplayName.ToLower() == "exchange-error-items")
                    {
                        exchangeErrorFolder = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!dbErrorFolder)
            {
                try
                {
                    //inbox.ODataType = "post";
                    var folder = _journalMailbox.MailFolders.Inbox.Request().CreateAsync(
                        new MailFolder()
                        {
                            DisplayName = "DB-Error_Items",
                        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    //inbox.ChildFolders.Add(folder);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            SmartLog.LeaveMethod("SetupMailBoxes()");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        SmartLog.LeaveMethod("SetupMailBoxes()");
    }
```

Where _clientSecretCredential is created like this:

```
_graphServiceClient = null;
    _options = new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud };
    _clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                    this.FindString(config.TenentID)
                    , this.FindString(config.AppID)
                    , this.FindString(config.Secret)
                    , _options);
    string[] apiScope = new string[] { this.FindString(config.Scope) };
    _token = _clientSecretCredential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(apiScope));
    graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(_clientSecretCredential, apiScope);
    IUserRequestBuilder _journalMailbox = _graphServiceClient.Users["journal@mycompany.com"];
```

The code seems correct, but everytime I execute "_journalMailbox.MailFolders.Inbox.Request().CreateAsync", I get the following error:

Code: ErrorInvalidRequest
Message: The OData request is not supported.
ClientRequestId:Some Guid.

From what I could figure out by searching on the internet, it has to do with the method using the wrong method to access the API. I mean like, its using "GET" in stead of "POST" or something like that, but that would mean its a bug in the MS code, and that would an unimaginably big oversight on Microsoft's part, so I can't think its that.

I've tried searching documentation on how to create subfolders, but of the preciously few results I'm getting, almost none has C# code samples, and of those, all are of the previous version of Microsoft Graph.

I'm really stumped here, I'm amazed at how hard it is to find any documentation to do something that is supposed to be simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turned out that I was blind again. Here is the correct code for what I was trying to do:

```
private void SetupMailBoxes()
    {
        SmartLog.EnterMethod("SetupMailBoxes()");
        MailFolder inbox = null;
        try
        {
            bool dbErrorFolder = false;
            bool exchangeErrorFolder = false;
            inbox = _journalMailbox.MailFolders.Inbox.Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (inbox.ChildFolderCount > 0)
            {
                inbox.ChildFolders = _journalMailbox.MailFolders.Inbox.ChildFolders.Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }                
            if (inbox.ChildFolders != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.ChildFolders.Count && (!dbErrorFolder  || !exchangeErrorFolder); i++)
                {
                    if (inbox.ChildFolders[i].DisplayName.ToLower() == "db-error-items")
                    {
                        dbErrorFolder = true;
                    }
                    else if (inbox.ChildFolders[i].DisplayName.ToLower() == "exchange-error-items")
                    {
                        exchangeErrorFolder = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                inbox.ChildFolders = new MailFolderChildFoldersCollectionPage();
            }
            if (!dbErrorFolder)
            {
                try
                {
                    var folder = new MailFolder()
                    {
                        DisplayName = "DB-Error-Items",
                        IsHidden = false,
                        ParentFolderId = inbox.Id
                    };
                    folder = _journalMailbox.MailFolders[inbox.Id].ChildFolders.Request().AddAsync(folder).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    inbox.ChildFolders.Add(folder);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            SmartLog.LeaveMethod("SetupMailBoxes()");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        SmartLog.LeaveMethod("SetupMailBoxes()");
    }
```